# Missing goals in weblogic-maven-plugin

Tags: java, web-services, maven, weblogic, weblogic-maven-plugin

I want to create a webservice client from the wsdl using `weblogic-maven-plugin`

Based on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/maven_deployer.htm#DEPGD383 I've generated the maven plugin using wljarbuilder from the server /lib

`java -jar wljarbuilder.jar -profile weblogic-maven-plugin`

I got `weblogic-maven-plugin.jar` with size just under 70MB which I've uploaded to artifactory and used in the maven build.

The problem is, that when I try to specify goal `ws-clientgen`, it complains that the goal doesn't exist. 
Here's the list of goals which should be available: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#CHEGICCC

but when I run with goal `help`, I get only this:

```
[INFO] --- weblogic-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:help (default) @ myapp ---
The following are the goals available currently in Maven
deploy
list-apps
redeploy
start-app
stop-app
undeploy
update-app
```

Why am I missing the goals? I got no warnings during creation of the plugin and didn't find any other options for the wljarbuilder

Comment: The documentation you referenced is for WLS 12.1.2.  Is that the version of WebLogic you have installed?  If not, find the documentation for the version of WebLogic you have.  If so, sounds like you should probably open a support case with Oracle.

Comment: Yes. The version is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed the wrong plugin to your artifactory. The first link http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/maven_deployer.htm#DEPGD383 in your question contains a note:

> This plug-in is deprecated in version 12.1.2 of WebLogic Server. 
>   Oracle recommends that you instead use the WLS 12.1.2 Maven plug-in

This old plugin is only used for deployment. That's why you only see start/stop/deployment related goals. You should follow the installation instruction on the second link you provided http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#CHEGICCC. The new plugin includes goals for development purpose such as `ws-clientgen`

Comment: Thanks, but that note doesn't really says much. What exactly is WLS 12.1.2 maven plug-in? I've found out that besides weblogic-maven-plugin, I can also get wls-maven-plugin, but the other link you posted once again says "lists all the weblogic-maven-plugin goals". Nothing about wls-maven-plugin. Now it works, but Oracle documentation really sucks. Thanks